# springockito xsd link is broken

Tags: spring, mockito, springockito

The location of Springockito's `mockito.xsd` seems to be broken.

We used 

`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/raw/tip/springockito/src/main/resources/spring/mockito.xsd`

But this does not work any longer. Does anyone know of a current URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like kubek2k's bitbucket repo is no longer accessible. Luckily someone made a github mirror [here](https://github.com/AngelInc/Springockito/blob/master/src/main/resources/spring/mockito.xsd).

Given that this repo is no longer accessible, a better / more permanent solution might be to create a local copy of `mockito.xsd` in your `src/main/resources` directory, and reference that instead.

For example, create `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/mockito.xsd` and change the xsd reference from:

```
....
http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/raw/tip/springockito/src/main/resources/spring/mockito.xsd">
```

to

```
...
http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito META-INF/spring/mockito.xsd">
```

**update 10-05-2016:**

- There's also a fork [here](https://github.com/kmoens/springockito/blob/master/springockito/src/main/resources/spring/mockito.xsd) -- it's based off version 1.0.7 from what I can see (which is more recent than Angellnc's github mirror above).
- And another [fork](https://github.com/springockito/springockito) here (this one is actually a mirror, but still 1.0.7)

**update 10-05-2016 2:**

Looks like there a 1.0.9 version also hosted here: https://bitbucket.org/duncan85/springockito/

Comment: This github version is incompatible with version 1.0.9 (the latest) of spingockito.

Comment: @HDave found another repo -- maybe you can make use of that one?

Answer (score 2):

[New repo location](https://bitbucket.org/duncan85/springockito/src/54e7ede42392c830be9fa3d69bd71fbe91ca1f93/springockito/src/main/resources/spring/mockito.xsd?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

The difference between the version in github (see first answer) and this one is the additional boolean attribute (useStaticMap) on the 'mock' element.
In our case the test were failing because mockito was expecting that boolean value in.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same problem and it works for me by changing xsi:schemaLocation
to
 either "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AngelInc/Springockito/master/src/main/resources/spring/mockito.xsd" or "http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito.xsd".